# Why isn't my autocomplete.js textfield responding to input (Drupal 7)?

Tags: drupal, autocomplete, drupal-7

I am trying to get auto complete to work for a text field in my Drupal installation. This is a large project, and I'm not yet familiar with Drupal and this large codebase. Please assume that I can make the simplest of mistakes.

Okay, so I've been following the simple tutorials on how to get my textfield to autocomplete.

I have a hook_menu():

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mod_name_menu() {
  $items = array();

  // Not important for this question. This is the submit URL.
  $items['apps/name/result'] = array(
    'title' => t('Result page'),
    'file' => 'mod_name.pages.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mod_name'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mod_name_course_display_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  // This is the relevant one!
  $items['apps/name/course-codes'] = array(
    'file' => 'mod_name.pages.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mod_name'),
    'page callback' => 'mod_name_course_code_list',
    'page arguments' => array('access content'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

I have a rather large form to work with, but the relevant piece for the textfield is as follows:

```
(mod_name.pages.inc)

function mod_name_basic_block_form($form, &$form_state) {

  [...]

  $form['search']['course_code'] = array(
    '#id' => 'course-code-textbox',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Course code'),
    '#default_value' => (isset($_POST['course_code']) ?
      strtoupper($_POST['course_code']) :
      (isset($_GET['course_code']) ?
        $_GET['course_code'] :
        '')),
    '#required' => FALSE,
    '#size' => '20',
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'apps/name/course-codes',
  );

  [...]

  return $form;
}

[...]

/**
 * Autocomplete for the course-code form.
 */
function mod_name_course_code_list($text) {
  $results = array('1' => 'Thing 1', '2' => 'Thing 2');
  drupal_json_output($results);
}

[...]
```

I have just kept the callback function a static array for now to see how the autocomplete behaves. I expect that when I type in the textfield, the throbber should throb and then I would see as autocompletes "Thing 1", "Thing 2" or similar. However, when I type in the textfield, nothing occurs. I do see a gray throbber on page load, but it does not animate while typing, blurring, or clicking.

When inspecting the page, I see that autocomplete.js is loaded in the Network tab. I also see that the input field has autocomplete attributes. I have tried both in Firefox and Chrome and neither produce any action whatsoever.

I am using `Drupal 7.32`

Any help or clues where to look next would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT:* I should mention that when I visit apps/name/course-codes, I do get a JSON response as expected of `{"1":"Thing 1","2":"Thing 2"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code in a test environment, and I got autocomplete to work by adjusting your test JSON to simply `$results = array('Thing 1', 'Thing 2')`

Comment: Thanks Terry. I found that by removing my module from a page manager panel, it worked. From my understanding, your solution would create it such that the label and value in autocomplete would be equal, whereas in the example above, the value is the key, and the text displayed is the value.